# Venn diagrams error working out the percentages of 2 sets?

Tags: venn-diagram

A Survey has been conducted for a group of students yo find out which social media do they use, the survey results show 40% used Instagram, 73% used Snapchat and 30% used both.

How many students didn't used any of them.

Any idea about it?

i am getting stacked on doing the calculations.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the percentages, their sum is larger than 100%, which means that the 40% that use Instagram and the 73% that use Snapchat include the 30% that use both. There are 4 groups of students:

- Only use Instagram: 40% - 30% = 10%
- Only use Snapchat: 73% - 30% = 43%
- Use both: 30%
- Use none: 100% - 10% - 43% - 30% = 17%